# Блок накладывается на блок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Uber</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная </a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="subheader_logo"><img src="icons/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                        <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                        <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
                        <a href="tel:+74957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="promo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
                    <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
                    <div class="promo_descr">
                        Компания UBER  динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место средитаксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы по заказам, компания начисляет бонусы запиковое время.
                        <br><br>
                        Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве.  Водители у насзарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.
                    </div>
                    <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #212121;;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 13px 70px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu .menu_link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.menu .menu_item {
    border-right: 2px dotted black;
    padding-right: 28px;
}

.subheader {
    height: 84px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.subheader .subheader_logo {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.subheader .subheader_official {
    margin-top: 6px;
    opacity: .6;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.subheader .subheader_call{
    margin-top: 19px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.subheader .subheader_phone {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 12px;
}

.subheader .subheader_btn {
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: 172px;
    height: 46px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #1EACC7 0%, #4CE2FF 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) inset;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже весь день бьюсь с этой проблемой, по идеи блок promo должен быть отдельным от subheader, но они накладываются друг на друга(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените стиль `header` на это

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое)